# I have a vector of characters say A,G,C,T. I want the longest sequence of A from the vector using R

Tags: r, vector, longest-substring

```
set.seed (12345)

data <- paste(sample(c("A","C","G","T"),100000,replace=TRUE,prob=rep(0.25,4)))
data <- ifelse(data=="A",1,0)
```

Suppose I convert the data into 1 (desired character) and 0 (else). Then take sum at each positions. If sum upto a position matches sum upto the next, we stop; otherwise we carry on the sum and store the sums at the positions. Then the maximum sum at corresponding position will give the maximum length of sequence.

I got the algorithm but can't code it. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

The [`rle` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html) is what you want here:

```
set.seed(12345)
data = sample(c('A', 'C', 'G', 'T'), 100000, replace = TRUE, prob = rep(0.25, 4))

run_lengths = rle(data == 'A')
(result = max(run_lengths$lengths[run_lengths$values]))
# [1] 10
```

Getting the *position* of the longest run is a bit harder. You can use `which.max` for that, but we’ve previously filtered out all non-`A` results. Instead, we can also set all non-`A` runs to `0` — that way, they’ll still be there, but won’t be the maximum:

```
only_a = ifelse(run_lengths$values, run_lengths$lengths, 0)
longest_run_index = which.max(only_a)
```

Now we need to calculate back from the `longest_run_index` to the index inside `A`. We do this by adding up the lengths of all the runs before this index:

```
index = sum(run_lengths$lengths[seq_len(longest_run_index - 1)]) + 1
data[index : (index + result - 1)]
# [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
```

Comment: Nice. Another thing which might be of interest to you is to be able to see those elements. Simply `out <- which(data=='A')`.

Comment: How can I know at which position the maximum sequence started ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @KonradRudolph. That helped. :)